# Javascript SVG clipto with clip rule (fabricjs)

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

There is the exemple in img
http://imgur.com/rFdcctc

I have a background where i put an image (phone case).
After that i put a rectangle on the top side (50% top). (canvas)
On that i put an svg that is an another mask (that follow the case curves).

The svg is the same as the entire background in size. So to only have the top of the SVG i "clip" a rectangle on to it.

```
    var clipTo = function(ctx) {
  var w = mask.width, h = mask.height;
  var x = -w/2, y = -h/2;
  var rx = 0, ry = 0;

  ctx.moveTo(x+rx, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x+w-rx, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x+w, y+(h/2)-ry);
  ctx.lineTo(x+rx,y+(h/2));
  ctx.lineTo(x,y+ry);
  ctx.closePath();
 };
mask.setClipTo(clipTo);
```

And it works fine. But when i put a dragable image on it the image is mask by the SVG but not the clip rectangle, as if the clip is still there. (in the image, the content of the red rectangle should be invisible)

I have found that there is a clip-rule :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clip-rule

that could maybe with luck enventually should do it, but i have no idea how to apply it in javascript (i use fabricjs)

So if someone has an idea... :)

Thank you

Comment: so are you clipping how many times the image? is unclear. i would help you but i need more precise code.

Comment: Just one time. In a canvas i put a rectangle in side i put a svg who is clipped (with the size of the rectangle. when i put an image on the rectangle the svg mask react as is was not clipped. (on the link on top the red rect should not be visible.